# count the occurrences of POS tagging pattern

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, pos-tagger

So I've applied POS tagging to one of the columns in my dataframe. For each sentence, I want to count the occurrences of this pattern: NNP, MD, VB.

For example, I have the following sentence:
communications between the Principal and the Contractor shall be in the English language

The POS tagging would be:
(communications, NNS), (between,IN), (the, DT), (Principal, NNP), (and, CC), (the, DT), **(Contractor, NNP), (shall, MD), (be,VB)**, (in, DT), (the, DT), (English, JJ), (language, NN).

Notice that in the POS tagging result, the pattern (NNP, MD, VB) exists and occurs 1 time. I'd like to create a new column in the df for this number of occurrences.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple counter function would perform what you desired!

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'POS':['(communications, NNS), (between,IN), (the, DT), (Principal, NNP), (and, CC), (the, DT), (Contractor, NNP), (shall, MD), (be,VB), (in, DT), (the, DT), (English, JJ), (language, NN)', '(Contractor, NNP), (shall, MD), (be,VB), (communications, NNS), (between,IN), (the, DT), (Principal, NNP), (and, CC), (the, DT), (Contractor, NNP), (shall, MD), (be,VB), (in, DT), (the, DT), (English, JJ), (language, NN)', '(and, CC), (the, DT)']})
```

Function:

```
def counter(pos):
    words, tags = [], []
    for item in pos.split('), ('):
        temp = item.strip(' )(')
        word, tag = temp.split(',')[0], temp.split(',')[-1].strip()
        words.append(word); tags.append(tag)
    length = len(tags)
    if length<3:
        return 0
    count = 0
    for idx in range(length):
        if tags[idx:idx+3]==['NNP', 'MD', 'VB']:
            count+=1
    return count
```

Output:

```
df['occ'] = df['POS'].apply(counter)
df

    POS     occ
0   (communications, NNS), (between,IN), (the, DT)...   1
1   (Contractor, NNP), (shall, MD), (be,VB), (comm...   2
2   (and, CC), (the, DT)    0
```

Comment: Thank you! But I encountered an error saying that 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. That's probably because the POS tag result is not in string, i.e. the format is [(communications, NNS), (between,IN), (the, DT)...] not ['(communications, NNS), (between,IN), (the, DT), ...']

Comment: Yes, I think that's the reason! :[ @cookieclatter

Comment: All good, I fixed that up :), thanks again!